# Object Required Error on Renaming Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have what I thought was a basic block of code but keep getting the Object Required error. I have a workbook with multiple sheets and want to iterate through to rename them. I have tried four different methods, seen in the commented-out blocks, to achieve this but all hit the same error.

```
Sub ModifyWS()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim a As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim nm As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 2 To Application.Sheets.Count
    a = "BOE" & CStr(i - 1)

    'Attempt 1
    Sheets(i).Name = a

    'Attempt 2
    'Application.Sheets(i).Name = a

    'Attempt 3
    'Set nm = Sheets(i).Name
    'nm = a

    'Attempt 4
    'wb.Worksheets(i).Name = a
Next

End Sub
```

Your help is always appreciated.

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: It works for me not sure why it does not work for you.

Comment: I just checked it in a new spreadsheet and it works for me too. Is there a potential confliction issue with other subs in the same workbook? What is a good way to prevent that?

Comment: to rule out obvious errors, please change `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` to `Set wb = ThisWorkbook` and change `Application.Sheets.Count` to `wb.sheets.count` and change `Sheets(i).Name` to `wb.sheets(i).Name` . These all assume the sub is meant to work on the workbook that contains it.

Comment: It is possible that other sheets have the same name.

Comment: Those are good modifications, Zerk. Thank you for that.

Comment: Dy.Lee, when they had the same name I got a "That name is already taken" error message.

Answer (score 0):

The code did work in a new spreadsheet. It seems I somehow corrupted my workbook with another module, but upon creating a fresh version it all started to work.

Comment: Have voted to close the question as it's just a corrupt workbook - not a lot anyone can do about that. :)